# Multiple urls mapped to same function

Tags: python, django, url

I have this url in my urls.py:

```
url(r'^showrooms/', include('apps.showrooms.urls')),
```

and i want to have another url like this(i.e w/o 's' of showrooms)

```
url(r'^showroom/', include('apps.showrooms.urls')),
```

but having two urls like above results in two urls mapping to same data which is not good from seo perspective.So the solution is to redirect showroom/ urls to showrooms/ urls, but how do i get to this as showrooms/ is pointing to set of urls in apps folder ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep it close to django you can use the `redirect` shortcut as found in the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Otherwise this is more like a webserver question, for apache there is [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) in which you can 301 redirect, and nginx has the [rewrite directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) which should suit your needs just fine!

Comment: but how do i do it.. i tried this:  url(r'^showroom/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/showrooms/'), name="redirect-showroom"),but this takes me to showrooms where as i want to go to say, showroom/profile/showroom_name .. ?

Comment: Hmm your example shows no sign of that you wanted it like that, please update your question with this info. Also, could you please provide us with your `urls.py` and `views.py` ?